# How can I let the javascript catch a signal from node and prompt a window right after that?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I want to emit a signal from the app.js. The ejs file should catch it and prompt a window. The problem is I have to refresh the page to see the window. Also it seems it will be always shown if I refresh it again.

How can I let the window prompt immediately right after I send the signal from app.js? And only show once?

in the app.js

```
socket.emit('example_signal')
```

in the sample.ejs file

```
socket.on('example_signal', function(){
    alert('hello world')
})
```

it seems I found the cause of this problem. if I wrote

```
io.sockets.emit('example_signal')
```

directly, then the signal will be caught immediately. If I wrote it as

```
 io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {
    io.sockets.emit('example_signal')
 })
```

it will somehow wait for the page refresh...

Hope it can help others who encounter the same problem

Comment: It should just work. Are you only emiting the signal when the page is reloaded or something?

Comment: @Quentin I started some sub process in the app.js. This process is triggered by another signal, but I think it's all the same. I just emitted the signal then wait for the show up of the window...which of course die not happen...I have to refresh the page. That was pretty weird.

Comment: @Quentin I found an answer for this...But still not very clear with why this would appear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {
>     io.sockets.emit('example_signal')
> })
> ```
>
> it will somehow wait for the page refresh...

Because that is what that code says:

*When the browser connects to the socket, emit a signal*

… and the browser will connect to the socket when the page loads.

Removing the event handler that waits for a new connection will, naturally, cause the line `io.sockets.emit('example_signal')` to run immediately instead of waiting for the event.